# OnTriggerEnter2D not called consistently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, unity3d-2dtools

A gif that shows the collision inconsistencies: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJz0c.gif

In my Unity2D game I have a slingshot (the player) firing marbles up at a wall (think [Puzzle Bobble](http://www.classicgamesarcade.com/game/21606/puzzle-bobble.html) type puzzle-shooter games). Each of the marbles is a **clone** of the prefab and each prefab has a **rigidbody** with **IsKinematic** checked along with a **CircleCollider** with **OnTrigger** checked.

When a marble collides with the two side walls I use **OnTriggerEnter2D()** and rotate the angle so it bounces off the walls at an angle. When the marble collides with the top wall it basically freezes, at which point I remove the **rigidbody** component and set a **"topObjects"** tag.

The inconsistencies occur when a marble collides with another marble. Sometimes the trigger function is called, other times it's not. The triggers seem random and unpredictable.

Here is my C# code for detecting the collisions and the behaviors that go along with it (attached to the marble):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RockMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.5f;
    private Vector2 direction = new Vector2(0, 1);

    // current angle
    private float currentAngleZ;
    // indendiary angle
    private float angleB;

    // rotation speed
    private float rot;

    // curving speed
    private float rotMod;

    // stops marble when collides with wall
    private bool IsMoving = true;


    void Start() {
    }

    void Update ()
    {

        if (IsMoving) {
            rot = RockSpawn.rot;

            currentAngleZ = transform.eulerAngles.z;

            rotMod = transform.position.x * -0.5f;
            // moves it forward + adds speed
            transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * speed, Space.Self);
            // curving
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, rotMod, Space.Self);
            if (transform.position.x >= 0) {
                // faster speed when near walls "gravity/magnetism"
                speed += transform.position.x * 8 * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (transform.position.x < 0) {
                // faster speed when near walls "gravity/magnetism"
                speed += transform.position.x * -8 * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        else {
            // when object is stationary
            speed = 0;
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){

        // if collides with another marble

        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "topObjects" ) {
            // get rid of rigidbody
            // can't have 2 rigidbodies when 2 objects collide
            Destroy(rigidbody2D);
            // freeze movement
            IsMoving = false;

            Debug.Log ("you collided with a marble");

            // freeze rotation
            this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0, Space.Self);

            // assign the new tag
            this.tag = "topObjects";
        }
        else if(collider.name == "TopWall")
        {
            Destroy(rigidbody2D);
            IsMoving = false;

            Debug.Log ("you broke the fourth wall!");
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0);

            this.tag = "topObjects";
        }
        else {
            // bounce off walls
            currentAngleZ = transform.eulerAngles.z;
            angleB = 360 - (2 * currentAngleZ);
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, angleB);
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**: Simply changing the Update() function to FixedUpdate() seems to made the trigger more consistent however there are still inconsistencies in how they're detected.

I tested rigidbody2d.velocity, transform.position and various other transform functions but Transform.Translate produced the best results with bouncing it off the walls, even though it just theoretically just teleports the object to a new location.

Reducing the speed also doesn't affect the consistency at all and neither does changing the size of the circle colliders.

Comment: In my experience, collision and trigger events are more consistent when using physics based movement, for example, `rigidbody.velocity`.

Comment: I think the problem is related to your walls. Your gif only shows collision inconsistency when the bubble bounces on a wall. Are your walls set up as triggers or are they just regular colliders?

Comment: The walls are set up as triggers as well (Polygon Collider with IsTrigger checked)

Comment: I just saw the note about your objects being kinematic. I think that might be the cause actually. http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/rigidbody2d-with-kinematic-rigidbody-will-not-cause-ontriggerenter2d

Answer (score 1):

OnTriggerEnter2D should work consistently no matter if you are using physics or not.

However, if a gameObject stays in touch with another gameObject, you'll only get the OnTriggerEnter flagged once, the very first moment they do collide. After that you can keep getting informed of whether the two gameObjects are still colliding by calling OnTriggerStay.

Then after they stop colliding, the OnTriggerEnter will reset and will trigger again when contacting other gameObject even if its the very same that was colliding before. Have you checked this?

Hope it helps, I would have post as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points, so forced to post as answer sorry if I shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try OnTriggerStay and let you know if it works.

Comment: Well, not saying you should use OnTriggerStay() necessarily but just that it happens like so, just to make the note in case it might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious things here:

1.) your gameobject has a Rigidbody2D, so you shouldnt move it through the transform but instead through the rigidbody with functions like:

```
rigidbody2D.MovePosition()
```

and

```
rigidbody2D.MoveRotation()
```

Just look them up in the Unity Documentation.

2.) Put all this into

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    ...
}
```

This is where everything concerning the physic engine goes in. 
Also plenty of resources online to read about it :)

Comment: I tried Rigidbody2d.MovePosition() and MoveRotation(), however it only succeeded in moving the marble partway up the screen then stopping completely. I checked and there were no other colliders at that point so it appeared to stop arbitrarily. Changing OnTriggerEnter to OnTriggerStay also didn't fix the problem and neither did moving the transformation code to FixedUpdate().

Comment: MovePosition works in absolute positions. that means if you want to move up you have to use     rigidbody2D.MovePosition(rigidbody2D.position + Vector2.up);

Answer (score -2):

It's my understanding that Kinematic RigidBodies cannot collide in 2D.  I'm still pretty new, but I have found this in a few answers with my own issues.  You should look into it more.